# Are atoms unstable in $d\geq 4$ spatial dimensions when quantum mechanics is taken into account?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, spacetime-dimensions, orbitals

I understand that in 3+1 dimensions according to classical physics atoms should be unstable however atoms are stable in 3+1 dimensions because the behavior of atoms is governed by quantum physics instead of classical physics.

I have read before that atoms cannot exist in 4+1 dimensions but I'm not sure if this is taking quantum mechanics into account. Are atoms possible in 4+1 dimensions when quantum physics is taken into account or are they still unstable even after taking quantum mechanics into account?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, note that different authors disagree on what should be the Coulomb potential $V$ in $d$ spatial$^1$ dimensions. We will assume that it satisfies Gauss's law, i.e.

$$ V(r)~\propto~\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} r^{2-d} &\text{for}& d~\neq~ 2, \\ 
\ln(r)&\text{for}& d~=~2. \end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$

We will here only discuss the quantum mechanical hydrogen atom with $d\geq 3$. Let us normalize the Hamiltonian as

$$ H~=~-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta - e_d^2r^{2-d} .\tag{2}$$

For a rigorous discussion of [unbounded operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), domains and [self-adjoint extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators), etc., see e.g. Ref. 1 and references therein. Let us here summarize the results:

- The hydrogen atom in three spatial dimensions $d=3$ is stable and has bound states.
- Four spatial dimensions $d=4$ is an interesting border case, where the Coulomb potential and the centrifugal potential have the same $1/r^2$ behaviour.  If we define a dimensionless constant
  $$ Z~:=~\frac{2me_{d=4}^2}{\hbar^2},\tag{3}$$
  then there are three cases, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370901/2451) Phys.SE post:

  1. $Z\leq 0$: The Hamiltonian (2) has no bound states, i.e. the hydrogen atom is ionized.
  2. $Z>1$: The Hamiltonian (2) is unbounded from below, i.e. the hydrogen atom is unstable.
  3. $0<Z\leq 1$:  It is possible to define asymptotic boundary conditions (ABCs) at $r=0$ / selfadjoint extensions of the Hamiltonian, such that the spectrum is bounded from below. Some of these extensions have bound states, others have not.
- In more than four spatial dimensions $d>4$, the hydrogen atom is unstable. Roughly speaking, for $d>4$ the Coulomb potential (1) dominates the $1/r^2$ centrifugal potential at sufficiently small radius $r$ close to the nucleus.
  The instability can be rigorously proven via e.g. the [variational method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_%28quantum_mechanics%29), cf. the following theorem.

  *Theorem. An attractive singular power law potential*
  $$  V(r)~\propto~  -r^{-n}, \qquad
  n~>~2,\tag{4} $$
  *has a spectrum that is unbounded from below, i.e. it has no ground state and is unstable.*

  *Proof of theorem:* Consider a normalized Gaussian test/trial wavefunction
  $$\begin{align}\psi(r)~=~&Ne^{-\frac{r^2}{2L^2}}
  ~=~Ne^{-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2L^2}}, \cr
  \int d^dr~|\psi(r)|^2 
  ~=~&\langle\psi|\psi \rangle~=~1,\end{align}\tag{5}$$
  where $N,L>0$ are two constants. For dimensional reasons, the constant $L$ must have dimension of length, and the normalization constant $N$ must scale as
  $$N ~\propto~ L^{-\frac{d}{2}}.\tag{6}$$
  The expectation value
  $\langle\psi| K|\psi \rangle$ of the kinetic energy operator
  $K=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta$ must scale as
  $$ 0~\leq~\langle\psi| K|\psi \rangle ~\propto~ L^{-2},\tag{7}$$
  essentially because the Laplacian $\Delta=\vec{\nabla}^2$ contains two position derivatives.
  The expectation value $\langle\psi| V|\psi \rangle$ of the potential (4) must scale as
  $$ 0~\geq~\langle\psi|V|\psi \rangle ~\propto~ - L^{-n}\tag{8}$$
  for similar reasons. Thus by choosing $L\to 0^{+}$ smaller and smaller, the negative potential energy $\langle\psi| V|\psi \rangle\leq 0$ beats the positive kinetic energy $\langle\psi| K|\psi \rangle\geq 0$, so that the average energy $\langle\psi| H|\psi \rangle$ becomes more and more negative,
  $$\begin{align} \langle\psi| H|\psi \rangle ~=~&\langle\psi| K|\psi \rangle + \langle\psi| V|\psi \rangle\cr 
  ~\to~& -\infty 
  \quad\text{for}\quad L\to 0^{+}.\end{align} \tag{9}$$
  Hence, the spectrum is unbounded from below. $\Box$

References:

1. M. Bures & P. Siegl, [Annals of Physics 354 (2015) 316](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2014.12.017), [arXiv:1409.8530](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8530).

--

$^1$ One may show that for small compact dimensions much smaller than the characteristic size of the hydrogen atom (as predicted by e.g. [string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory)), such dimensions get averaged over and can effectively not be felt by the hydrogen atom. In other words, one effectively only has to consider large spatial dimensions $\cong \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Just a side note. You can roughly understand the instability as follows. The kinetic energy scales as $1/r^2$ so for any potential that goes like $1/r^2$ or faster towards zero, the wave function does not push back hard enough when it is compressed and the particle falls to the origin. Such potentials are called singular potentials. For a pedagogical treatment see: A.M. Essin & D.J. Griffiths, "Quantum mechanics of the $1/x^2$ potential", Am. J. Phys. 74 (2006) 109.

Comment: Shouldn't the uncertainty principle eliminate the instability? An electron falling into the nucleus would be confined in a very small space, which would require it to have higher momentum, thus energy; at some point, I would expect that effect to balance out the attractive potential, producing a stable energy valley.

Comment: Hi Logan R. Kearsley. Thanks for the feedback. No, [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) does not block the instability. One may e.g. check the above Gaussian test/trial wavefunction satisfies HUP.