# Eigenstates of Conical Potential in 3-dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, eigenvalue

If we take an ordinary time-invariant Schödinger equation:
$$H|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle,$$
and use a conical potential $V(r) = A r$ we get a differential equation:
$$\left[-\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\right)\nabla^2 + A r\right]\psi\left(\vec{r}\right) = E\psi\left(\vec{r}\right).$$

In one dimensions this becomes the [Airy differential equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.2), with the [Airy function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html), $\psi_n(x) = N [\operatorname{sgn}(x-x_n)]^n \operatorname{Ai}(k|x-x_n|)$, giving normalizable solutions for values of $x_n$ fixed by the energy and inverse scale $k=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2Am}{\hbar^2}}$.

Are the eigenvalues and eigenstates known for the 2 and, especially, 3 dimensional cases? Even for the zero angular momentum states? I've asked about whether the resulting differential equation can be related to a standard one with known solutions [over at math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045985/which-standard-differential-equation-does-this-simplify-to) and don't have a response there, but I thought that someone here at physics.stackexchange might have a greater familiarity with this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255961/what-is-known-about-the-hydrogen-atom-in-d-spatial-dimensions/256007#256007). In $d$ spatial dimensions, your equation reads
$$
u''(r)+2m[E-V_\ell(r)]u(r)=0
$$
where the effective potential is
$$
V_\ell=V(r)+\frac{1}{2m}\frac{\ell_d(\ell_d+1)}{r^2}
$$
with $\ell_d=\ell+(d-3)/2$. The zero-angular momentum state has $\ell=0$, and therefore in $d=3$ dimensions the equation for $u(r)$ is identical to the 1D Airy equation, whose solution you already know. For $\ell_d\neq 0$ there doesn't seem to be analytical solutions. The asymptotic behaviour at $r\to\infty$ should be easy to calculate, inasmuch the centrifugal term is negligible as compared to the linear term $Ar$. Other properties of the system are not as easily estimated using analytical methods, but one can always resort to numerical methods.