# What would the periodic table look like in 2 spatial dimensions?

Tags: atomic-physics, spacetime-dimensions, elements

I looked at this question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/13094/, and I think it answers part of my question about how atomic physics would work, but I'm not sure.

How many orbitals would be in each energy level of a 2-dimensional atom? Would atoms even exist?

I'm assuming that all fundamental particles that exist in the third dimension are present here. I know that forces would be determined by inverse rules instead of inverse square rules.

Comment: Related post for $d\geq 3$: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222238/2451

Comment: This paper discusses the 2D periodic table: https://www.jstor.org/stable/40024865